# how to config nginix for reversproxy to other container

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I have an app that create a subdomain with optimized front-end for every user (*panel.userdomain.com*). I config my dns server but i don't know how to config nginx to map a container. I explain my process

1. register user, submit a domain, dns server (bind9) config,
2. select a template for front-end and optimize it
3. create a docker container with domain name
4. ******** **config nginx** ************
   [NGINX Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeCe0.jpg)
   I want when a client type *panel.userdomain.com* and come to my *nginx*, map him/his to optimized front-end container.

Comment: First of all, you should let Nginx know the new container with specific name. Have you achieved that?

Comment: Did you mean the configuration in default.conf

Comment: No, I mean you should let nginx be aware about the creation of containers, if not, how could nginx know which container it should map requests to?

Comment: I run a shell script to config and reload nginx service. My Problem is in nginx configuration to serve container :(

Comment: According to your post, especially in 4) part, I could see clients have already typed the right domain name. All you want to do is mapping the request to right container. For example, a client request your website with user named tom, so it would type `panel.tom.com/some/uri` ?

Comment: When a client type `panel.tom.com/some/uri` the request map to tom's _front-end_ _container_

Comment: I assume that Nginx need not do anything. Since you’ve already submit `panel.tom.com` to dns server, so Nginx should know it too. So just make Nginx proxy_pass $schema$http_host$uri, it should work.